# Localhost opens a specific file in browser instead of the www directory

Tags: localhost, ampps

I am having a problem with my localhost in browser. Instead of opening to a directory with all of my files in the www folder in my ampps server the localhost opens to a specific file in that directory. How do I get the localhost to open the www directory?

Comment: Please  be specific on which directory it is opening, what have you tried and is it a new installation?